# In a tmate session, how do I get the tmate session token again?

Tags: tmux

When the tmate session starts, the "ssh noetuhasentuhsntdoendunoe@tmate" command in the status bar at the bottom tells me how another person can connect. After I've been working, that is gone. How do I get back to that information?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. press `prefix` + `~` to list all previous tmux/tmate messages
2. press `prefix` + `:` to get tmux prompt. Then type `show-messages` command to get the same results as in 1).

I prefer using 1) because it's faster.

Comment: Note to future self: `prefix` probably means `Ctrl+B`

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work after detach/reattach. My typical situation is: reattached to a session logged in on a machine, that has no tmate available. What I do then is a combination of two answers here: I press `Ctrl-B + :` and enter `display -p '#{tmate_ssh}'`, which goes into the same mode as `Ctrl-B + ~` and prints the information there.

Comment: How can I debug further if no ssh session ID is shown after running `show-messages`?

Answer (score 17):

This one liner will return only the ssh command:

```
tmate display -p '#{tmate_ssh}'
```

Read-only ssh command:

```
tmate display -p '#{tmate_ssh_ro}'
```

Comment: This is actually a better answer if the session is running for a while and the initial information is not there anymore.

Comment: Sometimes is it necessary to specify the path of the socket. On debian e.g. `tmate -S /tmp/tmate/<socket_uid> display -p '#{tmate_ssh}`